# How to find particular pattern using regex?

Tags: php, regex, string, file, search

I have some .php files in a directory that calls a user defined function:

```
_l($string);
```

each time different string is passed to that function and all strings are static, (i.e. not a single string is entered by user input).

Now I want a script that can list down all the strings form all the files of that directory, which are passed into _l($string);
I had tried:

```
 $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($fp)) {
      $content .= fgets($fp, filesize($file));
      if(preg_match_all('/(_l\(\'.*?\'\);)/', fgets($fp, filesize($file)), $matches)){
         foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
           array_push($text, $value[0]);
         }
      }
   }
```

I get strings but not every strings those are in files, some strings are not match with given regex, so what are the condiotion that is required to get all the strings?

Comment: It may be because you have 2 calls to `fgets()`, try removing the one in the `preg_match_all` call and use `$content` instead.

Comment: tried, but this time all the strings disappeared which were fetched by not removing fgets(), only 1st string fetched.

Comment: Can you show an example where the strings are missed.

Comment: _l($string) as pattern in preg_match_all() is not called as function but rather as regex string ?

Comment: @jacouh yes, it will be consider as a pattern

Comment: @NigelRen there are lots of but I am giving you an example, string which is fetched: 
"people_trust_us", string that bypassed regex: "type_address_here", there are many strings.

Comment: You are only getting strings enclosed in single quotes `'`.  Try removing those or adding a character class with single and double quotes. But that will not catch variables if any are passed.

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to get strings in double `"` or single `'` quotes as the `_l()` function argument.

```
$string = file_get_contents($file);
preg_match_all('/_l\([\'"](.*?)[\'"]\);/', $string, $matches);
$text = $matches[1];
```

If needed you can add some optional spaces before and after the `(` and before the `)`:

```
'/_l\s*\(\s*[\'"](.*?)[\'"]\s*\);/'
```

Also, if the function can be used in a loop or `if` or something where it's not terminated by a semi-colon `;` then remove it from the pattern.